# Filtering in php laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a basic page.
I want to add filters on the page using check boxes. Each product will have certain properties, and should filter out based on the clicked check boxes.
How do I achieve this?

Right now this is what my page code looks like:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Products</h1>
    @if(count($products) > 0)
        @foreach($products as $product)
            <div class="well">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <img style="width:40%" src="/{{$product->photo}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                        <h3><a href="/products/{{$product->id}}">{{$product->name}}</a></h3>
                        <small> {{$product->description}}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>No posts found</p>
    @endif

@endsection
```

I am using php laravel

[image: Preview Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very naive way to achieve this using radio buttons, and it worked.

Add radio buttons with filters on the view page, and call the below function on button press.

```
public function filter (Request $request)
{
    switch($request->submitbutton) {
        case 'Filter':

            //get selected filters to display
            $c1 = $request->input('radio button selected');

            //run the query to filter the result
            $products = DB::select(DB::raw("QUERY TO FILTER"));
            return view('products.products')->with('products',$products);
        break;
        //to clear out the filter, or display everything
        case 'Clear':
            $products = DB::select(DB::raw("QUERY TO CLEAR FILTER"));
            return view('products.filter')->with('products',$products);
        break;
    }
}
```